# How to get QSize object for a particular text, if a text style is given

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt framework.

Suppose, I have a text "123456". I want to retrieve `QSize` object for this text, for a style `Normal`.

Then, I can find the width from `QSize` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use [boundingRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-1) method of `QFontMetrics` to get the bounding rectangle of the given string (and then `QRect::size`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html):

```
QFont font("times", 24);
QFontMetrics fm(font);
const QSize textSize = fm.size(0, "123456");
```

For other font styles than normal, you can use the QFont API on `font`, like `QFont::setBold()`.

Comment: I have a small problem. I just have a QString,for which,I dont know the font size and height. But,I want to know its width. How do I know its width in such case?

Comment: To get the width of a string, you need to know the font size. The width is different for each font size.